# 180 degree rotated half pyramid(pattern question in JAVA)

Tags: java

I am actually trying to print this pattern: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjkHN.jpg

```
import java.util.*;

public class ques5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int n = 4;
            // outer loop
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                // inner loop
                for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output I am getting is :   `*  ** *******`

Comment: You can use String.repeat(“ “, n-i) at the first inner loop and String.repeat(“*”, i) at the second inner loop

Answer (score 3):

Add `System.out.println()` at end of second inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.*;

public class ques5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int n = 4,m=1;
            // outer loop
            for (int i = n; i >=1; i--) {
                // inner loop
                for (int j = 1; j <= i - 1; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (int k = 1; k <= m; k++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
                m++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```